# Set attributed text to UIButton

Tags: uibutton, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set an attributed string to a button.

The definition of this function on swift is this

```
func setAttributedTitle(_ title: NSAttributedString!,
               forState state: UIControlState)
```

so I thought I would have to type it like

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(title:attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

but the correct is

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

why it is necessary to put `forState:` but not `title`? I don't get that.

And by the way what is the meaning of that underscore on the func definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how **methods** parameters work in swift. I emphasize **methods**, because this doesn't hold true for bare functions, i.e. `func` definitions outside a class scope.

By default the first parameter is given without an explicit name, which is instead mandatory for the others.

From the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_300)

> Methods in Swift are very similar to their counterparts in Objective-C. As in Objective-C, the name of a method in Swift typically refers to the method’s first parameter using a preposition such as with, for, or by, as seen in the incrementBy method from the preceding Counter class example. The use of a preposition enables the method to be read as a sentence when it is called. Swift makes this established method naming convention easy to write by using a different default approach for method parameters than it uses for function parameters.
>
> Specifically, **Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names both local and external parameter names by default.** This convention matches the typical naming and calling convention you will be familiar with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for expressive method calls without the need to qualify your parameter names.

The underscore means: this parameter has no external parameter name. For the first arguments of methods this is redundant, but you can use it for instance to change the default behavior discussed above.

For instance

```
class Foo {
    func bar(a: String, b: Int) {}
    func baz(a: String, _ b: Int) {}
}
```

will result in the following proper use of method calls:

```
var f = Foo()
f.bar("hello", b: 1)
f.baz("hello", 1)
```

Adding the `_` has the effect of making `b` a local name only, so you cannot do

```
f.baz("hello", b: 1)
```

Comment: Then tell me why `var attrString = NSAttributedString("Hello World", attributes:dictAttributes)` does not work and `var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes:dictAttributes)` work.

Comment: because that's not a method. It's a function and it has different default rules.

Comment: ah... can you translate this phrase to english? `this parameter has no external parameter name`

Comment: Pretty sure your example does not work because it is a class initializer which follows different rules than methods.  Also "external parameter" means just that, the definition does not have an external parameter defined.  Read the language definition as that is a precise term.

Comment: @RubberDuck an external parameter name is the name you use for naming the argument you pass to the method, like `forState`. `forState` is both a local and an external parameter name for the function. You can find lots of information about this in the official guide.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!!!  Now we are talking!!!! The answer is perfect now! Thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.